# Using overloaded assignment operator

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I have a `template<> class A` with a non-default constructor and an overloaded assignment operator:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
  public:
  A(T x);
  A(A<T> &parent);
  A<T> & operator=(A<T> &rhs);
};
```

And a `class B`, which has `A` as member, it's own overloaded assignment operator and a getter method for A

```
class B
{
  public:
  B();
  B& operator=(B &rhs);
  A<int> get_A();

  protected:
  A<int> *member;
};
```

I have defined the assignment operator and `A` getter method as follows:

```
B& B::operator=(B &rhs)
{
  *member = rhs.get_A();
  return *this;
}

A<int> B::get_A()
{
  return *member;
}
```

The assignment operator doesn't work in this case. Am I missing something here? I get the following error:

```
B.cpp(92): error: no operator "=" matches these operands
            operand types are: A<int> = A<int>
```

I also tried

```
B& B::operator=(B &rhs)
{
  A<int> temp(rhs.get_A());
  *member = temp;
  return *this;
}
```

in which case I get:

```
B.cpp(92): error: no instance of constructor "A<T>::A [with T=int]" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (A<int>)
    A<int> temp(rhs.get_A());
```

Comment: Did you mean `rhs.get_A();` in the first implementation?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo

Comment: You also don't seem to make `member` point to a valid object.

Comment: Your copy assignment and copy ctor take non-const lvalue references, which cannot bind to temporaries such as the return value of `get_A()`.

Comment: Do not make a member a pointer, needlessly.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't mean to use constructor chaining there. I made the member a pointer because A doesn't have a default constructor, and it's assignment depends on some conditions in B() constructor.

Comment: can you add something compilable/testable? I thing that you need to add `const` somewhere (like `const A<T>&`) and/or && (like `operator=(A<T>&& rhs)`) to make everithing work

Comment: Basically, I need to avoid using operator= to make everything work -.-"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1

regarding

```
A<T> & operator=(A<T> &rhs);
```

that should better be

```
A<T>& operator=(A<T> const& rhs);
```

---

### 2

regarding

```
B& B::operator=(B &rhs)
{
  *member = B.get_A();
  return *this;
}
```

that should better be

```
B& B::operator=(B const& rhs)
{
  *member = rhs.get_A();
  return *this;
}
```

---

### 3

regarding

```
  B() : member(4);
```

that should not compile.

it's difficult to say what it should be since `member` is declared as a pointer, while the value provided is an incompatible integer.

---

### 4

regarding

```
A<int> get_A();
```

that should better be

```
A<int> get_A() const;
```

so that it can be called on a `const` object.

---

### 5

regarding the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125116/using-overloaded-assignment-operator/25125181#comment39105448_25125181)

> **”** A is a bit more complicated and contains a linked list. The linked list has to be updated every time an object of A is copied

it does sound a bit fishy that an object has to be updated every time it's copied. the old `std::auto_ptr` class was almost like that, and it achieved the effect via a hack involving a special proxy reference class. it's *possible* that your objects are not really copyable but just movable, in which case, don't use the *copy assignment* operator for whatever the operation really is, but use e.g. an ordinary named member function.

Comment: The problem is, A is a bit more complicated and contains a linked list. The linked list has to be updated every time an object of A is copied. So I can't have a const rhs

Comment: same with copy-constructor ... adding some `const` on some mehtods could help as well

Comment: What does a constant reference mean?

Comment: @Harshad: it's not the reference that is constant, it is a reference to constant, which means that that referred to thing can't be modified via this reference. it also can be bound to an rvalue (i.e. temporary) and to a const object.

Comment: What if I need to modify the rhs too?

Comment: Okay, I understand. I can't overload the assignment operator in this case. I need to define another function, in which case RHS cas be modified. Sorry stupid mistake.

Comment: I'm working on an object similar to shared_ptr and auto_ptr, which basically manages pointers to the same data on OS memory, pinned memory and GPU memory. Similarity to auto_ptr is why the class looks fishy.